# SOS: Battleship Java (for statement & array dimensions)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, indexing

people!
So, I'm trying to make the Battleship game (classic!) in Java, with basic array and method knowledge.
I created a boolean board with 2 dimensions to place my boats and here's my code:

```
public void placerBateau(int x, int y, boolean dir, int longueur){
    int abs = this.x;
    int ord = this.y;
    this.longueur = longueur;

    if(!tabPlat[x][y]){
        if(dir){
            for(abs=ligne; ligne<ligne+this.longueur; abs++){
                tabPlat[abs][ord] = true;
            }
        } else {
            for(ord=colonne; colonne<colonne+this.longueur; ord++){
                tabPlat[abs][ord] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}


public class BatailleNavale {
public static void main(String [] args){
    boolean [][] tabPlat = { { false , false , false , false, false } , { false , false , false , false, false } , { false , false , false , false, false } , { false , false , false , false, false } , { false , false , false , false, false } ,  { false , false , false , false, false } };
    Plateau plat1 = new Plateau(tabPlat);
    plat1.placerBateau(2, 2, true, 2);
    plat1.tir(2, 2);
    System.out.println(plat1.toString());
}
```

Basically, to place my boat, I want to do a for cycle, and make true (change their initial value) every cell within the interval I defined in the for statement.
But I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
at Plateau.placerBateau(Plateau.java:39)
at BatailleNavale.main(BatailleNavale.java:6)
```

Which refers to the following line of code:

```
tabPlat[abs][ord] = true;
```

I understand what it stands for, but I don't get how can I have a problem with this.

PS - I'm very sorry for my english.

Comment: What is `ligne` and `colonne`?

Comment: this is Java not C++ :) just create array with boolean [][] tabPlat = new boolean [5][5]; it'll fill array with false. :)

Comment: There are three variables `ligne`, `colonne` and `longueur`. In order to help, we need to know where and how they are initialised.

Comment: If you had stepped through this with a debugger, you would have seen the problem straight away.

Answer (score 2):

The error is here:

```
ligne<ligne+this.longueur
```

You never change `ligne` or `longueur` so it goes on until it reaches beyond the array.

Same for `colonne<colonne+this.longueur`

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be here:

```
public void placerBateau(int x, int y, boolean dir, int longueur){
    int abs = this.x;//you are referring to instance variable instead of local parameter
    int ord = this.y;//same here
```

Try removing `this` keyword.

Comment: This seems to be intentional.

Comment: I don't think it's intentional, or correct. But it's a different problem to the one that's causing the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: That might solve a different problem, but it doesn't solve the one that's causing the error